# How to pass all values from one row in DataGridView to TextBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I use this but am facing problem with the conversion of `DataGridView` to `Integer`:

```
For Each i As DataGridView In dataGridView1.Rows
    textbox1.Text=dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString.Replace("\n",",")
Next
```

Comment: What does this have to do with HTML or SQL?  What is your question?  `am facing problem` doesnt tell us anything at all.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a `DataGridRow` but you're trying to use it like an `Integer`.

Just replace `dataGridView1.Rows(i)` with `i`:

```
For Each i As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView1.Rows
    textbox1.Text = i.Cells(0).Value.ToString.Replace("\n",",")
Next
```

`i` in this case is a `DataGridViewRow`, not a `DataGridView`, so I've adjusted that as well (you could omit `As DataGridViewRow` too if you have `Option Strict Off`).

Also, I would name `i` something better than `i` as it's not an index; you're iterating over the actual rows of the grid.

Lastly, I'm not sure why you're looping over the rows and overwriting the value of the textbox every time, seems like a mistake. If that's true and you need help with that, please ask a new question.

Comment: `For Each DataGridView In dataGridView1.Rows` isnt going to work either.  `DataGridViewRows` dont contain `DataGridView` objects

Comment: @Plutonix: indeed, I overlooked that. Answer updated.

Comment: when replace datagridview.row(i) with i i get this problem "La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet."

Comment: That means that somewhere in that line, an object was `null` when you tried to access a property on it. `i.Cells(0).Value`: either `i` is `null`, or `i.Cells(0)` was `null`, or `i.Cells(0).Value` was `null`. My guess is the latter. You should check if there is a value before calling `ToString()` on it. Put a breakpoint on that line and inspect each portion using the debugging tools in your IDE.

Comment: but datagridview is not null

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
For Each i As DataGridView In dataGridView1.Rows
```

The variable `i` is being set to a `DataGridView` as you are enumerating the `dataGridView1.Rows`

If you want `i` to be an integer:

- Use a `for` loop, not `for each`
- List item declare `i As Integer` not  `as DataGridView11
- Increment `i` from `0` to `dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1`

Like this:

```
For I As Integer = 0 to dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1
    Textbox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString.Replace("\n",",")
Next
```

Also note that this code has a logic flaw in `that TextBox1.Text` will end up being set to the value of the last rows value.

It looks like your intent was to append all the cell values together as comma separated string.

To do that, you need to use `Textbox1.Text &=` instead of `Textbox1.Text =`

That would look like this:

```
For I As Integer = 0 to dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1
    Textbox1.Text &= dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString.Replace("\n",",")
Next
```

Also note that this code will leave Textbox1.Text with a trailing comma.

Comment: when use textbox1 .text &=  i get the result but i don't get comma of the number for example i want to get 1,2,3 but i get 123

Comment: i don't get comma of the number for example

Comment: Okay, your code was replacing the newline with the comma.

Answer (score 0):

How to pass all values from one row !!!!!!
Answer :
you don't need to make (for) to get All values in one row .
if All data in DatagridView You can Try SelectionChanged :

```
  Dim StarttSelect As String

  Private Sub Dgrd_SelectionChanged1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
  System.EventArgs) Handles Dgrd.SelectionChanged 
    StarttSelect = ""
    StarttSelect = StarttSelect & Me.Dgrd.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
    StarttSelect = StarttSelect & Me.Dgrd.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
    StarttSelect = StarttSelect & Me.Dgrd.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
    StarttSelect = StarttSelect & Me.Dgrd.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
    textbox1.Text = StarttSelect 
End Sub
```